# How to add meta data to a video file

Tags: copyright

I tried to change the Meta data of a video file. 
My system runs on Windows. So I tried to change meta data through rightclicking on the file and going to the properties > details. After chaning some information and saving this error occured:

[image]

What happend next is that the video file couldn't be played in a videoplayer anymore. This is the error message in Windows Media Player:

[image]

I have to re-render my video file. But my question is: what is the best method for adding meta data to a video file? What is the best Tag editor application on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling for "mp4 metadata editor" brings up lots of candidates. Many of these will search online databases for tagging DVD movie rips, a feature I don't think you're looking for, but they also let you add and edit tags in most common container formats like MP4. Two you might look at are **MP3Tag** (yes, MP3) and **MetaX/MetaZ**.